# can i power a device with more output amperage than the device needs?

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage

I just brought a speaker that runs on 12v power supply. So i want use it on my car.
Can i power a speaker with a car battery 12v directly?

Speaker input: 12V, 1.25A
Car battery output: 12V

Comment: Yes as long as the DC polarity (+ - ) is correct, if you don't get that right it will damage it.

Comment: You should ask this question on this site instead of SU....https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 3):

You need to check voltages and polarity carefully, but to directly answer your question, yes.  Current is drawn, not pushed. So the speakers will use the current they require and not more.

Comment: Do it all the time with amateur radio transceivers, very common.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It will be perfectly safe.

A device that only requires a certain amount of current will not draw more from the supply than it needs.

Think of it this way:

Voltage is *pushed* to the device from the power supply, so an excessive voltage can easily damage the device.

Current is *pulled* from the supply by the device, so the device only draws the current that it requires, regardless of the maximum current the power supply is able to supply.